# Script dando erro de sintaxe após ;

Tags: javascript, jquery

Esse script dá erro:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#dataSolicitacao').datepicker({
                format: "DD/MM/yyyy",
                language: "pt-BR",
                minViewMode: 0;
        orientation: auto
    });
  });
</script>
```

Dá erro no ponto-e-vírgula após a linha `minViewMode: 0;` dizendo que **falta uma chave** `}` e depois dá erro nessa última chave `minViewMode: 0;` dizendo **erro de sintaxe**.

Como eu corrijo esse *script*?

Comment: troca o ponto e vírgula por vírgula.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tem um ponto e vírgula indevido dentro da inicialização do objeto. Só trocar por vírgula e o problema está resolvido:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#dataSolicitacao').datepicker({
            format: "DD/MM/yyyy",
            language: "pt-BR",
            minViewMode: 0,
            orientation: auto
        });
    });
</script>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Browser/DatePicker.js).

Answer (score 3):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dataSolicitacao').datepicker({
        format: "DD/MM/yyyy",
        language: "pt-BR",
        minViewMode: 0,
        orientation: auto;
    });
});
</script>
```

O problema é que depois do *minViewMode* você estava colocando um ponto e vírgula.

Comment: Respondendo ao BigOwn e ao Leonardo. Isso eu já havia feito e não funcionou. A data continua vindo no padrão americano.

Comment: Leonardo, o ponto-e-vírgula após o `auto` dá erro de sintaxe.

Comment: @pnet Me parece que o problema foi resolvido, certo? O fato de você ter um outro problema agora, significa que você precisa de outra pergunta. Se a fizer eu tento responder. Você sabe como funciona, aceite esta (a resposta que resolveu o problema) e crie uma nova.

Comment: Essa pergunta foi feita de forma errada. Eu já possuo uma outra pegunta. Fiz a pegunta, mas pensando em outra resposta. Ok, vou aceitar porque fiz a pergunta de forma errada. Não era isso que eu procurava. Há duas resposta iguais.

Comment: Na outra pergunta você fez uma coisa semelhante.

Comment: @pnet não há duas respostas iguais, uma funciona e outra continua dando com problema, só trocou de lugar. Pra variar uma resposta errada fica recebendo votos.

Comment: @bigown não vi que tinha postado uma reposta e sobre o ponto e virgula não me atentei e coloquei no final (mania). Sobre responder para "ganhar pontos", não estou aqui para isso. Já fui muito ajudado pelo pt.SO, pra mim pontos não faz diferença nenhuma. :)

Comment: @LeonardoCoelho, ok, pela regra do forum vou responder e fechar o post, mas ok. Obrigado pelo feedback e seu comentário foi oportuno.